# email validation using regular expression

Tags: php, javascript

i am using this regular expression for email validation but it is not allowing hyphen (`-`):

```
/^\w+([\.-_]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-_]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/
```

please any one tell me how can i do this?

Comment: I think that if you make it the first element in your range it will take the literal meaning of "-".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try escaping your hyphens:

```
/^\w+([.\-_]?\w+)*@\w+([.\-_]?\w+)*(.\w{2,4})+$/
```

the dash is reserved for ranges inside square brackets so if you want to make it a literal, you need to escape it.

Comment: ... or place it last: `[.\-_]` = `[._-]`

Comment: @jensgram - that works?  it removes it from being a "range" character?  never tried/knew that one

Comment: Yes, it does just that :) Placing it last makes it unambiguous since it *cannot* be a range character.

Comment: ya, that makes sense, can't range the closing bracket =)...your example looks like uneven eyes hah

Answer (score 3):

There is a function in PHP for this [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), would try to avoid using RegEx as much as posible. They are powerful but can get pretty hairy.

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Comment: yup I also agree you should better use filter_var over regex if possible.

Comment: yes, that does work, but wouldn't it be better to make sure the user has the correct format first before submitting to the server?  then there's no need to do a full round trip to check for errors.

Comment: The question is tagged as php,i thought it would be suitable to give a php solution. There is also ajax.